# SharePoint 2010 OOTB Approval Workflow Visualization

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, visio-services

SharePoint 2010 does a great job of giving the visualization of your workflow EXCEPT for the OOTB approval workflow.  That visualization looks horrible.  Business users need a better visualization and I do not want to reinvent the wheel here.  Does anyone know ANY way to modify/update the visualization that the OOTB approval workflow uses?  Why is it so different from a workflow created in SPD?